# .htaccess rewriterule with a period at the end

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I set this rule in my .htaccess

```
 RewriteRule (.*)/feyundco/ /$1?fq[ps_brand]=Fey+%26+Co. [P,L,R=301]
```

but when I reach the page, for example, example.com/search/feyundco the redirection doesn't work.
Same rule for other brands works like a charm

```
RewriteRule (.*)/modular/ /$1?fq[ps_brand]=Modular [P,L,R=301]
```

Where is the problem? The . at the end, the %26 (&) or what?
Thanks

Comment: Does the destination url work if you enter it in browser?

Comment: Yes, it perfectly works, like example.com/search?fq[ps_brand]=Fey+%26+Co.

Comment: Why are you using the `P` and `R=301` flags together? `P` is for proxy, which is not needed here.

Comment: Thanks @MikeRockett, I removed the P but the redirect still not working. I Don't understand why.